# How to create discord connection to my site

Tags: web, discord

Im trying to make a website for my discord community and i wana only users that are in my discord guild/server to be able to see the content of the site.

The idea is gotten from smash.gg site where it is possible to allow only people from the discord server to be able to participate in the tournament

Here is a article and screenshoot from it:
https://help.smash.gg/en/articles/2444130-asking-for-requiring-connections-in-tournament-registration

[image]

I serached for a while but i did not find how they are making this feature so i can use it for my site.

Did anyone give me some directions where and what to search for?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to look into **Discord OAuth2**;
https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2